# Why memory alignment in Nginx is required

Tags: c, memory-management, nginx

Recently I'm studying the source code of NginX. I found it quite interesting while I'm curious about the memory management design, what's the concern when they define the size of NGX_POOL_ALIGNMENT and NGX_DEFAULT_POOL_SIZE? And why they have such memory alignment design?

I really hope somebody could give me some tips about those issues, and we can have further discussion if you're also interested in NginX implementation and willing to share your experience with me :D.

BTW, I'm reading NginX 1.2.3 which is the stable version stated by their team.

Comment: SO is not a forum. So don't expect to have further discussions, here. And effectively such questions as you ask are usually better placed on the developpement list of the software in question. Very unlikely that  someone happens to know something about it, here.

Comment: All right, maybe I asked this question in a wrong place, sorry and thank you for reminding me about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably ask the developers of NginX. My guess is that they are just aligning stuff to a cacheline (or multiple of a cacheline).

Obviously they do that for performance.

Comment: this is not an answer but a comment.

Comment: Well, yes and no. The question is pretty localized in the form it has been asked (NginX), and in that sense it is almost unanswerable beyond for the 'ask the developers' note. But the underlying general question of _why memory alignment (beyond what malloc already guarantees) is (or may be) required_, then 'performance' by aligning to cacheline is an answer (the only other possible one I can imagine has to do with page alignment).

Comment: Thank you Analog File. Although you didn't directly answer my question :P. But I was indeed put this question in a wrong place. Thank you for answering my question!